# How to trigger an action once the search button in action bar is clicked?

Tags: android

I did the following but it didn't work

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
    {       

        startActivity(new Intent(NamesList.this,MainActivity.class)); 

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            search = (EditText) menuItem.getActionView();
            search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
            search.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

            String result = search.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the :: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }   


        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `search.setOnQueryTextListener()` to set a listener for user actions within the SearchView.

```
search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //show your toast here
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

or `search.setOnSearchClickListener()` to set a listener to inform when the search button is pressed. This is only relevant when the text field is not visible by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what im trying to do is showing the value of the search field once the search button is clicked such as showing it as a toast